# Do cabin upgrades do anything?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

So, the first upgrade category, Cabin, what does it do? What is it for?

What does Super Space do better than the default Space installment?

Answer (score 9):

It improves aerodynamics when pulling high (tall) cargo's, but I'm not sure if the game would simulate that, as there are numerous useless, just for visual enjoyment upgrades.

It doesn't unlock anything and doesn't have any additional features, so... yeah...