# Does the chosen chassis affect the available job offers?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I've seen [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89947/do-cabin-upgrades-do-anything), which has no accepted answer, it is implied that the cabin size is only a visual change and doesn't affect the gameplay.

But this is about the chassis. I've seen screenshots of trailers that (from the looks of it) just wouldn't fit on a 4x2 truck. So I'm wondering, if you refit a truck from 4x2 to a 6x2 or 6x4 do you only have the downside of the reduced tank capacity? Or do you gain anything, like the ability to tow larger trailers with more valuable goods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I downloaded a player profile with some play money (1 billion Euro, all skills maxed) and did some testing. I bought the smallest cabin and chassis and took a screenshot of the available jobs. Then I upgraded to the medium sized cabin, took a screenshot again, upgraded to the large cabin, took another screenshot. Same with the chassis.

Afterwards I compared the screenshots. The result: the jobs were always the same. So I guess the switchable parts are really just for show.